# Best way to save API data to a model variable in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a model that I made that looks like this

```
class UserModel {
    constructor(
        public title: String = '',
        public name: String = '',
        public type: String = '',
        public isActive: Boolean = false
    ) { }
}
```

and initialized a variable in the component as

```
userDetails: UserModel = new UserModel();
```

when i call and API to get the user details and try to save it to the response to the variable

```
this.http.get(userDetailURL).map(response => response.json())
.subscribe(success => {
    this.userDetails = success;
});
```

if the response has other properties than the ones I have specified in my model like

```
{
    type: 'user',
    name: 'Username',
    type: 'new',
    unwantedData: 'removeMe',
    isActive: true;
}
```

it also gets saved to the variable. Is this correct? Is there some easy way to filter out the unwanted data when saving the variable other than just looping through the object keys and saving them?

Comment: You could always do `this.userDetails = new UserModel(success.title, success.name, success.type, success.isActive)`

Comment: If you have full control over an api. I would suggest to include only the necessary data to the api endpoint. That way, the request would be even faster and without the unnecessary data.

Comment: `for (let key in this.userDetails) { this.userDetails[key] = success[key] }` was something I thought would help for large objects but is there some method where i can use destructuring? The other methods work fine for smaller objects but when the number of properties increase its a bit difficult to use them.

Comment: You could create a constructor that takes an object, and then does `this.title = obj.title` for each relevant property. That way it's simple to create an instance, and the messy code stays within your model

Comment: try with  this.userDetails = success as UserModel;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign specific fields to the object you can just do,

```
this.http.get(userDetailURL).map(response => response.json())
.subscribe(success => {
    this.userDetails.title = success.title;
    this.userDetails.name= success.name;
    this.userDetails.type= success.type;
    this.userDetails.type= success.type;
});
```